# What are the current and voltage ratings of the USB C CC1 (VCONN) pins?

Tags: usb-c

I can't seem to find this information, but obviously I searched wrong, or Google is weighing my earlier search history too much.

So, what are these power ratings exactly for the CC1 pin?

Comment: Check [this](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/USB-Type-C-VCONN-Requirements) out.

Comment: Are you asking what the USB standard says you can get using that pin, or are you asking what the physical limits are (which might be specific to a particular connector) when using it in a non-USB-spec-compliant application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid range for CC1/VCONN pin is 3.0 to 5.5V and connector pin is rated for 1.25A, and how much power is available depends on which devices you support.

Compare that to CC2 connector pin, which has a rating of 0.25A, and pull-up maximum voltage is 5.5v.

You can read the details from the USB standard which is freely available.

Answer (score -5):

Without an emarker chip, 3A at 20V.
With an emarker chip and certified 5A cable, 5A at 20V.

And with the newer extended power range feature and a EPR cable, 5A at 48V.

As far as specs go anyway. Any given cable or connector will vary.

Comment: This answer is not about VCONN but VBUS.

Comment: @Justme `VCONN Powered Devices (VPD) are a special class of USB Type-C Sink device which can provide a  functionality while ONLY being powered by VCONN from a USB Type-C Source port.`

Comment: The question is clear, it asks the voltage/current ratings of CC1 pin which also features as the VCONN pin. The question does not ask the ratings for VBUS voltage or current.